# How do you convert a pandas data frame into a numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with all the IBM prices (close, open, high, low) in it since 1962.
I would like to make a numpy array out of it with only closing prices.
I know you can use `numpy.asarray` but that command will keep all of the values (close, open, high, low). Does anyone know how to do the conversion and only keep close?

Comment: `df['close'].values` or `df['close'].to_numpy()`?

Comment: I don't meant o be harsh, but this can be looked up in the docs in less time than it took to write your question.

By the way;```df.loc[:, 'column_name_that_i_want'].to_numpy()```